# OpenXML: Issue adding images to documents

Tags: openxml

Up until now, this block of code has been using to build documents with text for several months with no snags.  I am now trying to dynamically add images.  I've spent about two days staring at code and researching and am at an end.  I suspect the issue is that relationships are not being created (more details below.)  Maybe not?

```
   //set stuff up...
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fsPat, true, new OpenSettings(){
    AutoSave = true,

    MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings = new MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings(MarkupCompatibilityProcessMode.ProcessAllParts,
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.FileFormatVersions.Office2007),

    MaxCharactersInPart = long.MaxValue
    });

    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
.
.Other stuff goes here
.

//now the fun...
Run r2 = new Run();
    // Add an ImagePart.
    ImagePart ip = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
    string imageRelationshipID = mainPart.CreateRelationshipToPart(ip); //
    using (Stream imgStream = ip.GetStream())
        {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("myfile.png");
        b.Save(imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    Drawing drawing = BuildImage(imageRelationshipID, "name"+imageRelationshipID.ToString(), 17, 17);
    r2.Append(drawing);
    p.Append(r2);
```

The image part is essentially copied from http://blog.stuartwhiteford.com/?p=33) and is running in a loop presently.  I also copied his BuildImage() function and use it as-is.

When I open the resulting docx, I see red Xs where the images are saying "This image cannot currently be displayed."

When I open the zip, the images will appear in root/media, but not root/word/media as I'd expect.  I also cannot find the images referenced in any of the relationship files.  Ideally they'd be in root/word/_rels/document.xml.rels.  You'll notice I changed how imageRelationshipID is set hoping to fix this.  It didn't.

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... It seems like OpenXML just hates me.  I copied AddImagePart code from like 3-4 places among trying other things--none of which lasted long--and just could not get relationships to form.  The implication I see is that they happen automatically with the AddImagePart function.

I ended up doing a complete workaround where I add all the pictures I might want to put and remove the Drawing nodes' parents of the ones I didn't want (Run nodes, generally.)  Since these are very small pictures, it's feasible and in ways more elegant than trying to add them as necessary since I don't have to keep track of where images are stored on disk.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I'm running into the exact same issue.  The image relationships are not getting created.

Comment: @tr4nc3 In my scenario I knew I always wanted one of 3 images to display in specific locations.  So I cheated and added them to those locations in my template word document.  I was then able to remove all the images that didn't match the desired 'image name' leaving me with just the one.  All 3 images were still embedded in media folder so the file size was marginally larger that it would have been otherwise. This only worked for me because a) limited image options b) small images (12x12 or something) c) I was using a template rather than constructing the document from scratch.

Comment: If that doesn't meet your needs, sorry I won't be able to help.  I never got the "add image" code to work in favor of the above solution.  My project's long-term result was that we eventually switched to constructing html and converting it to pdf.  Later still we ended up moving to Crystal Reports thanks to non-technical businessmen.  That's a whole different story to be told over beer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Great ingenuity! Unfortunately, in my case, this won't work.